# Function for Differential Equation for Malthusian Population Approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just rediscovered a program I made a few years ago on Khan Academy to model the [Malthusian population curve](https://www.khanacademy.org/differential-equations/malthusian-population-example-curve/6556683542593536), based on a differential equation, where $K$ is the population limit, $N$ is the population, and $t$ is time.
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=\frac1{8\log{t}}+\frac{(K-N)}{1.69}\frac{\sin(t)}t$$ It's sort of like a logistic curve, but with some tweaks to better fit real-life.

I was wondering how I should go about finding a function for $y$, the population, with respect to $x$, time. I already know the general logistic growth equation $$\frac{dN}{dt}=rt(1-\frac{N}{K})$$ and how to get to it, but I'm not sure how to tackle my differential equation.

Thanks in advance.

---

The numerical constants in the first equation are mostly just arbitrary - feel free to replace them with simpler integers if you like.

Comment: What you call ''equations'' are not equations because there is no $=$ in them. What is $y$ in $\frac1{8\log(x)}+\frac{(K-N_o)}{1.69}\frac{\sin(x)}x$ ? Sorry I cannot understand your question and what you are looking for.

Comment: @JJacquelin Sorry for the confusion. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N_K = N-K$, then we have a slightly simpler equation

$$ \frac{dN_K}{dt} + \frac{a\sin t}{t}N_K = \frac{b}{\ln t} $$

Using the standard first-order method, an integrating factor can be found as

$$ \mu(a,t) = \exp\left(a\int_0^t \frac{\sin \tau}{\tau}\ d\tau\right) = \exp\big(a \operatorname{Si}(t) \big) $$

where $\operatorname{Si}(t)$ is the sine integral. Then

$$ \mu \frac{dN_K}{dt} + \frac{d\mu}{dt}N_K = \frac{d}{dt}\big(\mu N_K\big) = \frac{b\mu}{\ln t} $$

$$ \implies N_K = \frac{1}{\mu}\int \frac{b\mu}{\ln t} dt = be^{-a\operatorname{Si}(t)}\left[\int_0^t \frac{e^{a\operatorname{Si}(\tau)}}{\ln \tau} d\tau + c\right] $$

If $N(0) = N_0$ then we have the solution

$$ N(t) = K + (N_0-K)e^{-a\operatorname{Si}(t)} + be^{-a\operatorname{Si}(t)}\int_0^t \frac{e^{a\operatorname{Si}(\tau)}}{\ln \tau} d\tau $$

The singularity at $t=1$ can be resolved by the Cauchy principal value. You may notice that this population model grows without bounds, similar to the logarithmic integral.